# Getting 404 publishing web service on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, windows-server-2008

I wrote a web service in VS 2012 and it works fine while debugging in VS.  I am now trying to publish it to the web server.  I keep getting "The resource cannot be found."  HTTP 404.  This is what I have done:

Verified code works in local debugger
Propped code to web server to the web site that is known to be working and hosting other regular .net applications (but none of them are web services - just regular sites/applications).
Installed HTTP Activation
Added .svc to MIME Types
Restarted IIS

Deploying to Windows Server 2008
.Net 4.0
Using VS 2012 for dev/debugging

What am I missing?

Comment: perhaps you are deploying it incorrectly  read the documentation here [C# msdn Xml Web Service deploying](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9w05e9b(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Open IIS on server and see you can view your service there. Make sure you have an application pool in IIS not in stopped mode.

Comment: If I open IIS on the server and do Manage Application->Browse all it does is it gives me a directory listing of the directory.

Comment: It looks like I'm doing everything I should according to the deployment docs.  

If I browse to 
https://<server>/<deployment dir>/<service name>
I get the generic 'you have created a service...' page.  So the service is up and running.  

But if I browse to:
https://<server>/<deployment dir>/<service name>/<endpoint>
I get a 404.  
So it must be some kind of deployment/config issue.  It all works locally, the service URL works on the server - it's just the endpoints all give me 404 on the server (but work locally).